# Is it better to store 1 email/file in Google Cloud Storage or multiple emails in one large file?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to do analytics on emails for some users. To achieve this, I am trying to store the emails on Cloud Storage so I can run Hadoop jobs on them. (Earlier I tried App Engine DataStore but it was having a hard time scaling over that many user's data: hitting various resource limits etc.)
Is it better to store 1 email/file in Cloud Storage or all of a user's emails in one large file? In many examples about cloud storage, I see folks operating on large files, but it seems more logical to keep 1 file/email.

Answer (score 2):

From a GCS scaling perspective there's no advantage to storing everything in one object vs many objects. However, listing the objects in a bucket is an eventually consistent operation. So, if your computation would proceed by first uploading (say) 1 million objects to a bucket, and then immediately starting a computation that lists the objects in the bucket and computing over their content, it's possible the listing would be incomplete. You could address that problem by maintaining a manifest of objects you upload and passing the manifest to the computation instead of having the computation list the objects in the bucket. Alternatively, if you load all the emails into a single file and upload it, you wouldn't need to perform a bucket listing operation.

If you plan to upload the data once and then run a variety of analytics computations (or rev a single computation and run it a number of times), uploading a large number of objects and depending on listing the bucket from your analytics computation would not be a problem, since the eventual consistency problem really only impacts you in the case where you list the bucket shortly after uploading.